# Detect for *crushed plants*

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In the map I'm making, Pvt. Rabbit (You) must try not to crush any planted carrots underfoot. If he does, I want it to be detected and then +1 to a scoreboard counting the number of times he has done it. My question is what is what would be the correct command to detect if he has crushed any planted carrots. At first I tried:

```
 execute @p[r=1000] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~0 ~ minecraft:carrot say ...
```

I won't use the say command once I've figured it out, but now I'll use that. It says that "there is no such block with name minecraft:carrot" which I completely get. Any Ideas about what to do?

Comment: Would checking for a dropped carrot item at the player's feet be enough, or are there other situations where carrots may be dropped that you want to avoid detecting?

Comment: No, there wouldnt be any other carrot dropped throughout the map. It is just for that one situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a dummy objective that we'll use to track items that are carrots:

```
/scoreboard objectives add isCarrot dummy
```

Then, on a clock, in this order:

1. Set that objective to 1 for all items that are carrots:

```
scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] isCarrot 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:carrot"}}
```

2. Have all carrots add a point to the nearest player:

```
execute @e[type=Item,score_isCarrot_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add @p carrotsCrushed 1
```

3. And then kill all carrot items:

```
kill @e[type=Item,score_isCarrot_min=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could detect whether the player is standing on dirt. A simple command to do that would be:

```
execute @p ~ ~-1 ~ testforblock ~ ~ ~ dirt
```

If they crush the crop, it turns the farmland under them into dirt, and the command block will output `true`.

Comment: I guess I should have made the question a little clearer. You know when you fall down from a height onto crops they break, and that it what I what to try to detect. In my command above, I was trying to test for the actual dropped item 'minecraft:carrot'

Comment: I don't think there's a way to detect dropped items of a particular type. I think I know another way to do this though, I'll work on it.

Comment: @kittycat3141 You can detect an entity based on its NBT data with `/testfor` *or* apply a label with `/scoreboard` to target the item afterwards. Example: `/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] OBJ 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:carrot"}}`

Comment: @Skylinerw For some reason I thought that was impossible. Good to know.

Comment: Thanks @kittycat3141! It works well, but I dont want the player to be able to go back over the dirt after the crop has been crushed. Is there anyway to fix that? At first I tried using [ /execute @e[type=Carrots] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecraft:carrots setblock ~ ~ ~ carrots ] but [ Entity type 'carrots' is invalid ] Any ideas?

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN You could summon a marker armor stand at each of these blocks, and only add the points if the player is not within a block of one.